# Spying on a function used as a constructutor

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

In one of my unit tests I need to spy on a function which is used as a constructor by another function with `Sinon` library. As per their documentation

> ...`sinon.spy(object, "method")` creates a spy that wraps the existing function object.method. The spy will behave exactly like the original method (including when used as a constructor)... 
>   But so far I have failed to make it work even when trying to spy on a constructor called within the test function let alone called by another function.

Unit test:

```
   it('constructor was called.', () => {
        const Foo = require('../app/foo');
        const fooModule = module.children.find(m => m.id.includes('foo.js'));
        const fooSpy = sinon.spy(fooModule, 'exports');
        const f = new Foo(5);
        expect(fooSpy).calledOnce;
    });
```

Function to be instantiated:

```
const Foo = function(param) {
    console.log('Foo called with: ' + param);
};

Foo.prototype.bar = function(x) {
    console.log(`Foo.prototype.bar() called with x: ` + x);
};

module.exports = Foo;
```

When I step with debugger I can see the function at `const fooSpy = sinon.spy(fooModule, 'exports');` being replaced by the spy (has all all `sinon` properties added like `calledOnce` and so on...) however when on `new Foo(5);` it appears that `Foo` is a non spy object.

I thought this might be a scoping or reference error but I can't seem to find where else `Foo` would be defined apart from within `module.children`. It is not on `global` neither its on `window` since its running on `node`.

Currently the test of course fails with:

```
Foo called with: 5

AssertionError: expected exports to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
    at Context.it (test/fooTest.js:18:23)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The module requiring/importing is at a different level than the code you are testing. The modules are already loaded when your testing code runs. You don't have the same access to `module.exports` that you do over an Object referenced in your current execution context, like the instance of `Foo`, `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not really with the `sinon.spy` API, but with how Node modules import functions. When calling `sinon.spy`, unless we are testing a callback function, we usually need an Object to be the context on which we want to spy on a particular method. This is why your example tries to access the `exports` Object of the `foo.js` module. I am not aware of Node giving us access to such an Object.

However, for your example to work, we don't need access to the Foo module's `exports`, we could simply create a context of our own. For example:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");

const expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe("foo", function () {
    it('constructor was called.', function () {
        const context = {
            Foo: require("../app/foo"),
        };

        const fooSpy = sinon.spy(context, "Foo");

        new context.Foo(5);

        expect(fooSpy).to.be.calledOnceWith(5);
    });
});
```

Of course, the above test is a working solution to the problem provided in your example, but, as a test, it is not very useful because the assertion just verifies the line above it.

Spies are more useful when they are *dependencies* of the System Under Test (SUT). In other words, if we have some module that is supposed to construct a `Foo`, we want to make the `Foo` constructor a Spy so that it may report to our test that the module did indeed call it.

For example, let's say we have `fooFactory.js` module:

```
const Foo = require("./foo");

module.exports = {
  createFoo(num) {
    return new Foo(num);
  },
};
```

Now we would like to create a unit-test that confirms that calling the `createFoo` function of the `fooFactory.js` module calls the `Foo` constructor with the specified argument. We need to override `fooFactory.js`'s `Foo` dependency with a Spy.

This returns us to our original problem of how can we turn an imported (constructor) Function into a spy when it is not a method on a context Object and so we cannot overwrite it with `sinon.spy(context, 'method')`.

Fortunately, we are not the first ones to encounter this problem. NPM modules exist that allow for overriding dependencies in required modules. Sinon.js provides a [How-To](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) on doing this sort of thing and they use a module called [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).

proxyquire will allow us to import the `fooFactory.js` module into our unit-test, but also (and more importantly) to *override the `Foo` that it depends on*. This will allow our unit-test to make `fooFactory.js` use a `sinon.spy` in place of the `Foo` constructor.

The test file becomes:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");

const expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe("fooFactory", function () {
    it("calls Foo constructor", function () {
        const fooSpy = sinon.spy();
        const { createFoo } = proxyquire("../app/fooFactory", {
            "./foo": fooSpy,
        });

        createFoo(5);

        expect(fooSpy).to.be.calledOnceWith(5);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `proxyquire` was exactly what I needed.